# UICollectionView background behind cells is black

Tags: swift

I'm creating a UICollectionView inside of a UICollectionView programmatically, however the background behind the cells of my nested UICollectionView is a black color, and I can't figure out how to change it. Below you will find my code, as well as an explanation of what I've tried thus far.

App Simulator(parts of app blocked out):

[image]

UICollectionView1.swift

```
private var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout? = nil
private var collectionView: UICollectionView? = nil

collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout!)
collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

collectionView?.register(UICollectionView1Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
collectionView?.dataSource = self
collectionView?.delegate = self

view.addSubview(collectionView!)

collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        (collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 125))!,
        (collectionView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -75))!,
        (collectionView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0))!,
        (collectionView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0))!
        ])

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let homeTestCollectionViewCell = cell as! HomeTestCollectionViewCell

    switch(indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        UICollectionView1Cell.cellLabel?.text = "Sponsored:"
        UICollectionView1Cell.collectionViewIndex = indexPath.row
        break
    case 1:
        UICollectionView1Cell.cellLabel?.text = "Trending Near You:"
        UICollectionView1Cell.collectionViewIndex = indexPath.row
        break
    case 2:
        UICollectionView1Cell.cellLabel?.text = "Hot:"
        UICollectionView1Cell.collectionViewIndex = indexPath.row
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

UICollectionView1Cell.swift

```
var cellLabel: UILabel? = nil
var subCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout? = nil
var subCollectionView: UICollectionView? = nil
var collectionViewIndex: Int?

cellLabel = UILabel()
cellLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
addSubview(cellLabel!)
cellLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": cellLabel!]))

subCollectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
subCollectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
subCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: subCollectionViewLayout!)
subCollectionView?.register(UICollectionView2Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "subCell")
subCollectionView?.dataSource = self
subCollectionView?.delegate = self
addSubview(subCollectionView!)
subCollectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[v0]-8-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": subCollectionView!]))
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0(20)]-12-[v1]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": cellLabel!, "v1": subCollectionView!]))

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let subCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "subCell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionView2Cell
    return subCell
}
```

UICollectionView2Cell.swift

```
var label: UILabel = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupFrames()
}

func setupFrames() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    label.textColor = UIColor.blue
    addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-2-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": label]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-2-[v0]-2-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": label]))
}
```

I believe that the issue is occurring in my UICollectionView2Cell.swift file. in the setupFrames() method, I tried the following:

1) Setting the backgroundView = nil
2) backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
3) Setting the isOpaque property to "False"

However, the background behind my nested cells is still black, and I cant figure out why.

Could you guys please point me in the right direction?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

In my UICollectionView1Cell.swift file, I had the following code:

```
subCollectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
subCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: subCollectionViewLayout!)
```

I was setting the backgroundColor before the the collectionView had even been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've got this issue in the case of iOS 14.0.1. In all other iOS, collection view was fine. I've solved it by changing my CollectionView's background colour in View Did Load

```
myCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but my collection view was in a view. Background was black and I created it via the IB. Had to use collectionview.backgroundColor = .white because I couldn't figure out why the background was changing to black

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).